visual studio hace referencia a una ruta que no existe ¿Como hago para que no la busque?
Hace un año en la facultad un amigo me recomendo instalar DevExpress el cual nunca use para nada. Hace unos dias se me rompio el disco duro que lo contenia entonces ya no existe. Pero el visual studio cada vez que ejecuto cualquier proyecto me aparece el siguiente error buscando la direccion del archivo.

Y por qué no desinstalas la extensión o quitas la configuración que hace que esté buscando eso?? Igual que lo instalaste lo puedes desinstalar y quitar de tu configuración...
